# How to close an existing file for edit in Perforce after using edit command?

Tags: perforce

When you need to edit a file in Perforce, you need to checkout file or use 'p4 edit' command to make the file writeable.

But somehow I don't want to edit it anymore. So is there any command that will allow me to close it edit status, i.e. make the file readonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do one of these two things:

- Use `p4 revert` to discard your local changes and revert to the latest revision from the depot.
- Use `p4 submit` to submit your local changes as a new revision in the depot.

Either way, you will be left with a read-only (synced and unopened) depot revision in your workspace.